# Stack table by Pyspark SQL

Tags: python, pyspark

I have this table that looks like this
[image]

I want to stack them up using spark that look like this.

```
+-----------+--------+-----+
|CountryName|variable|value|
+-----------+--------+-----+
|      Aruba|    1960|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1961|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1962|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1963|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1964|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1965|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1966|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1967|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1968|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1969|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1970|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1971|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1972|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1973|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1974|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1975|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1976|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1977|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1978|  NaN|
|      Aruba|    1979|  NaN|
+-----------+--------+-----+
```

But for some reason I keep getting this table with the 4th column having the same value as the third column. Is there any other way I can do this?

```
+-----------+-----------+----+-----------+
|CountryName|CountryCode|Year|CO2Emission|
+-----------+-----------+----+-----------+
|      Aruba|        ABW|1960|       1960|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1961|       1961|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1962|       1962|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1963|       1963|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1964|       1964|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1965|       1965|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1966|       1966|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1967|       1967|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1968|       1968|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1969|       1969|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1970|       1970|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1971|       1971|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1972|       1972|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1973|       1973|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1974|       1974|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1975|       1975|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1976|       1976|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1977|       1977|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1978|       1978|
|      Aruba|        ABW|1979|       1979|
+-----------+-----------+----+-----------+
```

here is my code:

```
spark.sql("""
  select CountryName, CountryCode, stack(55,'1960',1960,'1961',1961,'1962',1962,'1963',1963,'1964',1964,'1965',1965,'1966',1966,'1967',1967,'1968',1968,'1969',1969,
  '1970',1970,'1971',1971,'1972',1972,'1973',1973,'1974',1974,'1975',1975,'1976',1976,'1977',1977,'1978',1978,'1979',1979,
  '1980',1980,'1981',1981,'1982',1982,'1983',1983,'1984',1984,'1985',1985,'1986',1986,'1987',1987,'1988',1988,'1989',1989,
  '1990',1990,'1991',1991,'1992',1992,'1993',1993,'1994',1994,'1995',1995,'1996',1996,'1997',1997,'1998',1998,'1999',1999,
  '2000',2000,'2001',2001,'2002',2002,'2003',2003,'2004',2004,'2005',2005,'2006',2006,'2007',2007,'2008',2008,'2009',2009,'2010',
  2010,'2011',2011,'2012',2012,'2013',2013,'2014',2014 ) as (Year, CO2Emission)
  from CO2level
""").show()
```

Please help me. I'm extremely new to Spark. I later need to join it with another table so it please advise me!

Comment: because you are stacking them like this only

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily by using the [create_map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map) and [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.read.table("CO2level")
df = df.withColumn(
  "other_cols",
  f.create_map(*[col for col in df.columns if col != "CountryName"])
)
df = df.select("CountryName", f.explode("other_cols").alias("variable","value"))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: It's throwing error on my end. Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3305.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 26.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 26.0 (TID 430) (67afd66f2f86 executor driver): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use null as map key.

Comment: Can you add a `df.printSchema()` of your `df = spark.read.table("CO2level")` in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `CO2Emission`'s value is exactly as `Year`, is because your columns' name **are** number (e.g.1960, 1961, etc), so when stacking `'1960',1960`, you stacked a **string `'1960'`** on top of an **integer `1960`**. The easiest way to fix it is wrapping your integer column names in a pair of backticks ``, like so "'1960', `1960`".

###### This is my sample dataset

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('C1', 'c1', 1, 2, 3),
    ('C2', 'c2', 4, 5, 6),
    ('C3', 'c3', 7, 8, 9),
], ['name', 'code', '1960', '1961', '1962'])

+----+----+----+----+----+
|name|code|1960|1961|1962|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  C1|  c1|   1|   2|   3|
|  C2|  c2|   4|   5|   6|
|  C3|  c3|   7|   8|   9|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

###### Select using backticks

```py
(df
    .select('name', 'code', F.expr('stack(3, "1960", `1960`, "1961", `1961`, "1962", `1962`)'))
    .show()
)

+----+----+----+----+
|name|code|col0|col1|
+----+----+----+----+
|  C1|  c1|1960|   1|
|  C1|  c1|1961|   2|
|  C1|  c1|1962|   3|
|  C2|  c2|1960|   4|
|  C2|  c2|1961|   5|
|  C2|  c2|1962|   6|
|  C3|  c3|1960|   7|
|  C3|  c3|1961|   8|
|  C3|  c3|1962|   9|
+----+----+----+----+
```

###### Shorten your code

You might already aware that the long `select` with all hardcoded columns doesn't do anything good, not to mention the schema might change and mistakes could happens. You can use a for loop to get the column names and build a string instead of wring them down.

```py
cols = [f'"{c}", `{c}`' for c in df.columns if c not in ['name', 'code']]
# ['"1960", `1960`', '"1961", `1961`', '"1962", `1962`']

(df
    .select('name', 'code', F.expr(f'stack({len(cols)}, {",".join(cols)})'))
    .show()
)

+----+----+----+----+
|name|code|col0|col1|
+----+----+----+----+
|  C1|  c1|1960|   1|
|  C1|  c1|1961|   2|
|  C1|  c1|1962|   3|
|  C2|  c2|1960|   4|
|  C2|  c2|1961|   5|
|  C2|  c2|1962|   6|
|  C3|  c3|1960|   7|
|  C3|  c3|1961|   8|
|  C3|  c3|1962|   9|
+----+----+----+----+
```